# Retreiving all the data from mysql using php and forms based on user entry value

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I Have a Database in this form

```
  IDNo             Column1           Column2         .............    
  12341
  12342
  12343  
    .......
```

I am Providing a form to user n telling user to enter IDNO in form so that the user can retrieve the respective idno info

If user enters 12341 in form and submit then the output will be the info of 12341
i.e
      IDNO            COUMN1          COLUMN2         .........
     12341             213              1231           .....

this will be the output and for that i am using the below code

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
<td><p align="center"> Hallticket Number : <input type="text" name="id" id="id" maxlength="10"></p></td>
<input type="submit" id="submit" class='btnExample' value="Click here to get your Result">
</form>
<?PHP

$user_name = "admin";
$password = "123456";
$database = "exam";
$server = "localhost";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM jbit WHERE htno='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
echo "
<center><table id='mytable' cellspacing='0'  border=3 align=center>
<tr>
<TH scope='col'>SUBJECT CODE</TH>
<TH scope='col'>SUBJECT</TH>
<TH scope='col'>INTERNAL MARKS</TH>
<TH scope='col'>EXTERNAL MARKS</TH>
<TH scope='col'>TOTAL MARKS</TH>
<TH scope='col'>CREDITS</TH>
<TH scope='col'>RESULT</TH>
</tr><center>";          

while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=center>" . $db_field['subjectcode'] . "</td>";
if ($db_field['credits']=="0")
{
echo "<td align=center><font color='red'>" . $db_field['subject'] . "</font></td>";
} else {
echo "<td align=center>" . $db_field['subject'] . "</td>";
}
echo "<td align=center>" . $db_field['im'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=center>" . $db_field['em'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=center>" . $db_field['tm'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=center>" . $db_field['credits'] . "</td>";
if ($db_field['credits']>"0")
{
echo "<td align=center> <font color='green'><b> PASS </b></font></td>";
} else {
echo "<td align=center> <font color='red'><b> FAIL </b></font> </td>";
}
echo "</tr>";

}
```

Now What i want is , If my user enter 1234 instead of 12341 or 12342 in form and submit

then the above code doesnt execute the output or shows invalid idno

but i want is if user enters 1234 instead of 12341 or 12342 vice versa or 123 instead of 12341 or 12342 viceversa then output should be all the info of all IDNO starts with 1234 
or 123 i.e

If user enter only 12 or 1 or 123 or 1234 in form and submits then the output should not be a invalid idno or empty , it should show all the columns idno ehich starts with the user submited value

first the output should be

```
   IDNO
  12341
  12342
  12343 with links
```

If user clicks on 12341 then the output should be

```
 IDNO          COLUMN1            Column2            ...
12341            321                323             ....
```

What should be done??

Answer (score 0):

Your sql should use `LIKE` operator: [LIKE operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM jbit WHERE htno LIKE '$id%'";
```

That should give you

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM jbit WHERE htno LIKE '1234%'";
```